# Use ConnectionString from Configuration in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using the recommended approach to configure Serilog with ASP.NET Core.

How to get ConnectionString from configuration in method Main to configure SQL Server sink?

```
public class Program {
  public static Int32 Main(String[] args) {

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .MinimumLevel.Debug()
      .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
      .Enrich.FromLogContext()
      .WriteTo.Console()
      .CreateLogger();

    try {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
      return 0;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      return 1;
    } finally {
      Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }

  }

  public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(String[] args) {

    IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

    builder
      .UseSerilog()
      .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder => {

      builder
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configuration) => {

          IWebHostEnvironment environment = context.HostingEnvironment;

          configuration
            .AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"settings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", false, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        }) 
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

    });

    return builder;      
  } 
}
```

I am using:
- Serilog: 2.9.0
- Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer: 5.3.0

In:
.NET Core 3.1

Comment: You can use `ReadFrom.Configuration()`: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#external-using-serilogsettingsconfiguration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the environment:

```cs
var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

Then use it to manually configure a builder just like you're doing below:

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true)
    .AddJsonFile($"settings.{environment}.json", false, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

Then get the connection string like normal:

```cs
var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("...")
```